# How to add Social Media icons to TN3Gallery?

Tags: wordpress

How can I add social media icons to my wordpress gallery plugin called TN3Gallery ?

http://goo.gl/h0nXB

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="javascript:void((function(){var e=document.createElement('script');e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');e.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');e.setAttribute('src','http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r='+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e)})());"><img style="margin: 0 0 -5px 0;" onclick="doPinIt();" src="http://www.tiptopnest.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/pinitbutton.jpg" alt="Pin It" /></a>
```

This code lets you pin all images on the page.